# If Column B indicated by #NA is different from the data below #NA, then use the data with the indicator #NA

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to code on how to have the same data with the #N/A row with the data below on it. I will provide an example to further explain the process. Thanks guys[image]

Comment: are the non-error cells in col a formulas or text?

Comment: It is a formula. I used vlookup thats why it has #N/A value

Comment: You could use: IFERROR(value, value_if_error). Place your vlookup as value and required value as value_if_error.

Comment: It is okay if the #N/A is not removed. What I need is the row with #N/A on column B should have the same data below it like in the image provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should run through columns A and B fairly quickly.

```
Option Explicit

Sub bFromNA()
    Dim i As Long, str As String, e as long

    With Worksheets("sheet2")

        e = .range("A:A").specialcells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlerrors)(1).row

        For i = e To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            If IsError(.Cells(i, "A")) Then
                str = .Cells(i, "B").Value2
            Else
                .Cells(i, "A") = str
            End If
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```